# Calling a method to try and rerun through a block of code

Tags: java

I'm trying to compare the cost of a user's phone usage under plans from three
different providers. I can get as far as entering the usage details but once entered I try to call the method to rerun from the if statement but it just displays the main menu again and stops. I want it to run through the entire if statement from the start again

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainMenuSelection {
    
    public static int menuSel() {       
    int menuSel ;       
    System.out.println("ENTER USAGE DETAILS MENU\n");
    System.out.println("Please select an option from the menu:");
    System.out.println("1.Phone Call");
    System.out.println("2.SMS ");
    System.out.println("3.Data usage");
    System.out.println("4. Return to main menu");
    
    
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
    System.out.println("Enter selection: ");        
    menuSel = in.nextInt();
    
    while (menuSel < 1 || menuSel >4){
          System.out.println("Value must bebetween 1 and 4, plese try again.");
          System.out.println("Enter your selection: ");
          menuSel = in.nextInt();
        }
    
    return menuSel;
                
}
public static int mainMenuSelection() {

    System.out.println("MAIN MENU\n");
    System.out.println("Please select from the menu:");
    System.out.println("1. Enter Usage details");
    System.out.println("2. Display Cost under provider 1");
    System.out.println("3. Display Cost under provider 2");
    System.out.println("4. Display Cost under provider 3");
    System.out.println("5. Clear usage details");
    System.out.println("6. Exit System");
    
    int mainMenuSelection;
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your selection: ");
    mainMenuSelection = userInput.nextInt();
    
    //return mainMenuSelection;
    
    while (mainMenuSelection < 1 || mainMenuSelection >6){
          System.out.println("Value must bebetween 1 and 6, plese try again.");
          System.out.println("Enter your selection: ");
          mainMenuSelection = userInput.nextInt();
        }
            
    System.out.println("You chose selection " + mainMenuSelection + "\n");
    return mainMenuSelection;
    
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");

        int callLength = 0;
        int numSMS = 0;
        int numberOfMB = 0;

        int numberofCalls;
        int callTime;
        int totalcallTime = 0;

        int mainMenuSelection = mainMenuSelection();

        if (mainMenuSelection == 1) {

            int menuSel = menuSel();
            if (menuSel == 1) {

                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter the number of phone call you have made? ");
                numberofCalls = in.nextInt();

                for (int i = 0; i < numberofCalls; i++) {
                    Scanner callInput = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("How long was the call in seconds?");
                    callTime = callInput.nextInt();

                    totalcallTime = callTime + totalcallTime;

                }
                System.out.println("Your total number of calls is " + numberofCalls);
                System.out.println("Your total call time is " + totalcallTime + " seconds" + "\n");

            } else if (menuSel == 2) {
                System.out.println("Enter the number of SMS messages: ");
                //int numSMS;
                Scanner userNumSMS = new Scanner(System.in);
                numSMS = userNumSMS.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Your number of SMSs is " + numSMS + "\n");

            } else if (menuSel == 3) {
                System.out.println("Enter the amount of data in MB: ");
                //int numberOfMB;
                Scanner userNumMB = new Scanner(System.in);
                numberOfMB = userNumMB.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Your amount of data in MB is " + numberOfMB + "\n");

            } else {
                mainMenuSelection(); // go back to main menu

            }

        } else if (mainMenuSelection == 2) {
            //Display cost under provider 1

            double callCost = 0.03 * totalcallTime;
            double smsCost = 0.10 * numSMS;
            double dataCost = 0.02 * numberOfMB;
            double totalCostProvider1 = callCost + smsCost + dataCost;

            System.out.println(totalCostProvider1);

        } else if (mainMenuSelection == 3) {
            //Display cost under provider 2
            double callCost2 = 0.04 * totalcallTime;
            double smsCost2 = 0.12 * numSMS;
            double dataCost2 = 0.04 * numberOfMB;
            double totalCostProvider2 = callCost2 + smsCost2 + dataCost2;
            System.out.println(totalCostProvider2);

        } else if (mainMenuSelection == 4) {
            //Display cost under provider 3
            double callCost3 = 0.05 * totalcallTime;
            double smsCost3 = 0.11 * numSMS;
            double dataCost3 = 0.03 * numberOfMB;
            double totalCostProvider3 = callCost3 + smsCost3 + dataCost3;
            System.out.println(totalCostProvider3);

        } else if (mainMenuSelection == 5) {
            //clear usage details 

        } else {
            System.out.println("Exiting System");
            System.exit(0);

        }

        mainMenuSelection = mainMenuSelection();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codes run from top to bottom. Therefore, after the `int mainMenuSelection = mainMenuSelection();` and the `if-else` statement is run, the code would run once again for the `mainMenuSelection = mainMenuSelection()` and ends, as there is nothing left in the block.

A fairly simple solution would be using a `while` or `do-while` loop with a boolean checking if the user entered the number `6` to exit the system.

You can try this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    /* 
     * Your variables here
     */
    boolean isExit = false;

    while(!isExit) {
        int mainMenuSelection = mainMenuSelection();

        if (mainMenuSelection == 1) {
                // menuSel codes here
        } else if (mainMenuSelection == 2) {
                // Display cost under provider 1
        } else if (mainMenuSelection == 3) {
                // Display cost under provider 2
        } else if (mainMenuSelection == 4) {
                // Display cost under provider 3
        } else if (mainMenuSelection == 5) {
                // Clear usage details
        } else {
            System.out.println("Exiting System");
            isExit = true;
        }

    }
```

Hopes this answer helps you well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a loop. Your main method has an exit condition so you can essentially loop forever by wrapping the code in your main method with a while loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  while(true) {
    // your main method code in here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you need to edit your code above in good formatting.

I have added a while loop in your main. Also, whenever any unwanted number the loop will exit using a break; and that in turn stops the program.

```
mainMenuSelection = mainMenuSelection();
```

I have deleted the above line from the code so you just need to call it once at the beginning of the code.

Let me know if you need sth else!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainMenuSelection {

    public static int menuSel() {
        int menuSel;
        System.out.println("ENTER USAGE DETAILS MENU\n");
        System.out.println("Please select an option from the menu:");
        System.out.println("1.Phone Call");
        System.out.println("2.SMS ");
        System.out.println("3.Data usage");
        System.out.println("4. Return to main menu");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter selection: ");
        menuSel = in.nextInt();

        while (menuSel < 1 || menuSel > 4) {
            System.out.println("Value must bebetween 1 and 4, plese try again.");
            System.out.println("Enter your selection: ");
            menuSel = in.nextInt();
        }

        return menuSel;

    }

    public static int mainMenuSelection() {

        System.out.println("MAIN MENU\n");
        System.out.println("Please select from the menu:");
        System.out.println("1. Enter Usage details");
        System.out.println("2. Display Cost under provider 1");
        System.out.println("3. Display Cost under provider 2");
        System.out.println("4. Display Cost under provider 3");
        System.out.println("5. Clear usage details");
        System.out.println("6. Exit System");

        int mainMenuSelection;
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your selection: ");
        mainMenuSelection = userInput.nextInt();

        //return mainMenuSelection;
        while (mainMenuSelection < 1 || mainMenuSelection > 6) {
            System.out.println("Value must bebetween 1 and 6, plese try again.");
            System.out.println("Enter your selection: ");
            mainMenuSelection = userInput.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("You chose selection " + mainMenuSelection + "\n");
        return mainMenuSelection;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int callLength = 0;
        int numSMS = 0;
        int numberOfMB = 0;

        int numberofCalls;
        int callTime;
        int totalcallTime = 0;

        while (true) {

            int mainMenuSelection = mainMenuSelection();

            if (mainMenuSelection == 1) {

                int menuSel = menuSel();
                if (menuSel == 1) {

                    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Enter the number of phone call you have made? ");
                    numberofCalls = in.nextInt();

                    for (int i = 0; i < numberofCalls; i++) {
                        Scanner callInput = new Scanner(System.in);
                        System.out.println("How long was the call in seconds?");
                        callTime = callInput.nextInt();

                        totalcallTime = callTime + totalcallTime;

                    }
                    System.out.println("Your total number of calls is " + numberofCalls);
                    System.out.println("Your total call time is " + totalcallTime + " seconds" + "\n");

                } else if (menuSel == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Enter the number of SMS messages: ");
                    //int numSMS;
                    Scanner userNumSMS = new Scanner(System.in);
                    numSMS = userNumSMS.nextInt();

                    System.out.println("Your number of SMSs is " + numSMS + "\n");

                } else if (menuSel == 3) {
                    System.out.println("Enter the amount of data in MB: ");
                    //int numberOfMB;
                    Scanner userNumMB = new Scanner(System.in);
                    numberOfMB = userNumMB.nextInt();

                    System.out.println("Your amount of data in MB is " + numberOfMB + "\n");

                }
            } else if (mainMenuSelection == 2) {
                //Display cost under provider 1

                double callCost = 0.03 * totalcallTime;
                double smsCost = 0.10 * numSMS;
                double dataCost = 0.02 * numberOfMB;
                double totalCostProvider1 = callCost + smsCost + dataCost;

                System.out.println(totalCostProvider1);

            } else if (mainMenuSelection == 3) {
                //Display cost under provider 2
                double callCost2 = 0.04 * totalcallTime;
                double smsCost2 = 0.12 * numSMS;
                double dataCost2 = 0.04 * numberOfMB;
                double totalCostProvider2 = callCost2 + smsCost2 + dataCost2;
                System.out.println(totalCostProvider2);

            } else if (mainMenuSelection == 4) {
                //Display cost under provider 3
                double callCost3 = 0.05 * totalcallTime;
                double smsCost3 = 0.11 * numSMS;
                double dataCost3 = 0.03 * numberOfMB;
                double totalCostProvider3 = callCost3 + smsCost3 + dataCost3;
                System.out.println(totalCostProvider3);

            } else if (mainMenuSelection == 5) {
                //clear usage details 

            } else {

                System.out.println("Exiting System");
                System.exit(0);
                break;

            }
        }

    }
}
```